Does the sum of two concave maximizable functions is maximizable?
Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are strictly concave and maximizable functions, that is, there exists $x^f,x^g\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\operatorname{argmax}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)=x^f$ and $\operatorname{argmax}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}g(x)=x^g$. Is it true that the sum $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is maximizable? It is immediate to show that the sum is strictly concave, but I am having difficulty showing its optimality. Any help will be appreciated.

Take a sphere $S$ large enough that both $x^f$ and $x^g$ are inside $S$.
Let $a = \max_{x \in S} f(x) $ and $b = \max_{x \in S} g(x)$.  Since $f$ has a unique maximum at $x^f$, $a < f(x^f)$.  Now for any $x$ outside $S$, there exist $t \in (0,1)$ and $y \in S$ such that $y = t x + (1-t) x^f$.  By concavity,
$f(y) \ge t f(x) + (1-t) f(x^f)$, i.e.
$$f(x) = \frac{f(y) - (1-t) f(x^f)}{ t} \le  \frac{a - (1-t) f(x^f)}{t}$$
Moreover, as $\|x\| \to \infty$, $t \to 0+$, and so $f(x) \to -\infty$. Similarly for $g$.   And thus if $R$ is large enough, we can be sure that
the maximum value for $f + g$ on the compact set $\{x: \|x\| \le R\}$ is greater than any value for $f + g$ outside that set.

If $S$ contains $x^f$ don’t we have $a = f(x^f)$?

@msantama He means the spherical shell, not the interior. Thanks, Robert!
